# How does the password in .git-credentials work?

Tags: git, github

- Where is this password used?
- If I were to show this password to others, how is this a security risk?
- Does this password contain login information to github?
- How would I deactive this password if accidentally shown to others?

Any answers to any of these questions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The file `.git-credentials` is used by default for the `store` credential helper, so it should only exist if you're using that credential helper.  The password is used whenever you're making a Git request over HTTP to one of the servers listed in the file if you're using the `store` credential helper.  For example, if you have your GitHub credentials stored this way, then they'll be used by Git when talking to GitHub.

The password in the file may be your account password or it may be a token.  GitHub is going to remove the use of account passwords in the future in favor of having everyone use a token or SSH key.  This is because your account password can be used to log in as you, and your token is much more restricted and cannot be used to perform those operations.  Using a personal access token or an SSH key is strongly advised in all situations even though it's not yet required.

Like all bearer credentials, you should not expose them to others because anyone who sees them can use them and gain access to everything that credential allows.  Since using an account password with GitHub is only allowed if you're not using 2FA, if you're using your account password here and it gets compromised, then that party has full access to your account and you'll need to change your password immediately.  If it's a token, you can go into the personal access token (PAT) settings and either re-issue the token, or remove it and add a new one.  Most PATs are issued with at least `repo` scope, so it will grant access to all your private repositories, plus whatever other access you've granted with additional scopes.